# 433 MHz Module Can't Working at ESP32 using Arduino IDE

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I have already read https://stackoverflow.com/a/65546448/23156066 as a reference and, I used that code.

However, during my testing using that code. My receiver can't receive anything and I don't know how to debug my transmitter.

I have alredy check my wiring. Here is my wiring cofiguration.

Transmitter:

```
    ESP32 GND <---> Transmitter GND
    
    ESP32 3.3v <---> Transmitter VCC
    
    ESP32 TX2(GPIO17) <---> Data
```

Receiver:

```
    ESP32 GND <---> Transmitter GND
    
    ESP32 3.3v <---> Transmitter VCC
    
    ESP32 TX2(GPIO16) <---> Data 0
    
    Not Connect <---> Data 1
```

This is my 433MHz Module:

[433MHz Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nraQK.jpg)

This is the ESP32 Version I used:

[ESP32 Version Dev Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkZmn.jpg)

Transmitter:

```
    #include <RCSwitch.h>
    #define TXD2 17
    
    RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      mySwitch.enableTransmit(TXD2);
      mySwitch.setPulseLength(311);
    }
   
    void loop() {
    /* See Example: TypeA_WithDIPSwitches */
    mySwitch.switchOn("01010", "10000");
    Serial.println("Switch On");
    delay(2000);
    mySwitch.switchOff("01010", "10000");
    Serial.println("Switch Off");
    delay(2000);
    }
```

Receiver:

```
    #include <RCSwitch.h>
    RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();
    
    #define RXD2 16
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.print("Ready to receive.");  
      mySwitch.enableReceive(RXD2); 
    }
    
    void loop() {
     if (mySwitch.available()) {  
     Serial.print("Received ");
     Serial.print( mySwitch.getReceivedValue() );
     mySwitch.resetAvailable();
      }
    }
```

What should I do?

FYI, I have already tried another method (using hardware serial) as well, but the result remains the same.

I would like to obtain a solution for my issue, such as code that has been revised by seniors in this forum and the correct usage concepts. For now, I am only using the concepts that I understand

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the Arduino Stack Exchange forum, it's very quiet. Are there no other solutions available? @zvone

Comment: No idea. I just think it will be even more quiet here with this kind of question... but maybe you get lucky...